# Correct way to pause & resume an std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, stdthread

I am using an `std::thread` in my `C++` code to constantly poll for some data & add it to a buffer. I use a `C++ lambda` to start the thread like this:

```
StartMyThread() {

    thread_running = true;
    the_thread = std::thread { [this] {
        while(thread_running) {
          GetData();
        }
    }};
}
```

`thread_running`  is an `atomic<bool>` declared in class header. Here is my `GetData` function:

```
GetData() {
    //Some heavy logic which needs to be executed in a worker thread
}
```

Next I also have a `StopMyThread` function where I set `thread_running` to false so that it exits out of the while loop in the `lambda block`.

```
StopMyThread() {
  thread_running = false;
  the_thread.join();
}
```

It works well. The thread starts & stops without crashing.

This C++ code is used on iOS, Android, OS X and Windows. My application UI has a button which requires me to start & stop the thread on a button press; this button can be frequently used in some occasions. I can see a split second delay in UI while stopping or starting the thread.

**My question is:** *In C++, is this a correct way to start/stop a thread frequently ?* I think that with this logic I am creating a new thread every-time. And as I understand, creating a new thread makes the OS allocate lot of new resources which can be time-consoming. And I think this is the mistake I am doing. How can I avoid this ?

How can make use of the same thread without allocating new one repeatedly throughout the application lifecycle, and just play/pause it when required ?

Comment: The delay may also be you waiting for the old thread to exit.  (If you have two threads using the same `thread_running` value, you will have grief!)

Comment: You can pause a thread by making it wait on a `std::mutex`.

Comment: Beware:  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031209-00/?p=41573 for why a general `suspend_thread` function is not going to be a good idea.  (The example is about C# on Windows, but the principles apply everywhere.)  If you do use a mutex to make it wait, you will have to think carefully about blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Not exactly on point, but related: take a look at boost::coroutine, it's a pretty cool thing.

Comment: `std::mutex` + `std::condition_variable`. The `resume` function will just do ` `notify_one`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Isnt there a `std:: C++` way of creating a `coroutine` ?

Comment: @NelsonP, boost coroutines are pretty powerful. They can be paused/resumed from everywhere, and you can pass objects into a coroutine, and out from at any point. AFAIK they work by saving the context of the coroutine and then performing context switches when it needs to be stopped or resumed. I don't think you can quickly write something like that yourself only with std.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall implementing coroutines and context switches is not that [difficult](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/coroutine.hpp).

Comment: I know this question is old, but I just want to point out that "button pressed frequently" is still glacially slow compared to the speed of a computer. Stop and start the thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the classical example for the use of a condition variable. You wait on a mutex and notify a thread when a certain condition is fulfilled; this way you don't need to allocate a new thread when you need one, but this is not always a good thing, if you wish to save memory. An alternative would be a coroutine yielding to another coroutine when data is needed, which is arguably prettier. You need to implement coroutines yourself, or use a ready-made library, such as `boost.coroutine`.

### Example

```
::std::condition_variable cv_;
::std::mutex m_;
bool data_is_ready_{};

StartMyThread()
{
  ::std::thread([this]
    {
      for (;;)
      {
        ::std::unique_lock<decltype(m_)> l(m_);
        cv_.wait(l, [this]{ return data_is_ready_; });

        // do your stuff, m_ is locked
        data_is_ready_ = false;
      }
    }
  ).detach();
}
```

To notify:

```
{
  ::std::unique_lock<decltype(m_)> l(m_);

  data_is_ready_ = true;
}

cv_.notify_one();
```

As it is often faster to free the lock before notifying, than vice-versa.

Comment: Haven't you missed to lock the mutex inside the thread? cv.wait will not lock it, it expects a **locked** mutex and will **unlock** it during wait.

Comment: A nit-pick. Why to fully qualify `std` namespace ? It's ugly and useless unless you did something nasty and wrong.

Comment: why do you use a `.detach` at the end. Wouldn't this make it a `daemon` thread ?

Comment: Yeah, it's a detached thread, but he knows about join(), so he can do it differently.

Comment: One Last question all of you participants : `thread_running` is an `atomic<bool>` as I have said in my question. I can just keep returning out of `GetData()` if `thread_running` is false. And only execute the complete method logic if `thread_running` is true. Wouldn't that be more efficient here ?

Comment: @NelsonP With the above approach you don't need atomics anymore as reads and writes are protected by a mutex. That said I envisioned data_ready_ as an alias for thread_running as the thread should not run if data is not ready.

Comment: @user1095108 Accepted. But I want to compare another solution here. Is there a disadvantage is I do the same with an `atomic<bool> variable thread_running` ?

Comment: I have asked a follow up question to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553609/approach-of-using-an-stdatomic-compared-to-stdcondition-variable-wrt-pausing). Please reply if anyone can. thanks