# Approach of using an std::atomic compared to std::condition_variable wrt pausing & resuming an std::thread in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread, stdatomic

This is a separate question but related to the previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544480/c-correct-way-to-pause-resume-an-stdthread/40544769?noredirect=1#comment68344743_40544769)

I am using an `std::thread` in my `C++` code to constantly poll for some data & add it to a buffer. I use a `C++ lambda` to start the thread like this:

```
StartMyThread() {

    thread_running = true;
    the_thread = std::thread { [this] {
        while(thread_running) {
          GetData();
        }
    }};
}
```

`thread_running`  is an `atomic<bool>` declared in class header. Here is my `GetData` function:

```
GetData() {
    //Some heavy logic
}
```

Next I also have a `StopMyThread` function where I set `thread_running` to false so that it exits out of the while loop in the `lambda block`.

```
StopMyThread() {
  thread_running = false;
  the_thread.join();
}
```

As I understand, I can pause & resume the thread using a `std::condition_variable` as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544480/c-correct-way-to-pause-resume-an-stdthread/40544769?noredirect=1#comment68344743_40544769) in my earlier question.

**But is there a disadvantage if I just use the `std::atomic<bool>` `thread_running` to execute or not execute the logic in `GetData()` like below ?**

```
GetData() {
    if (thread_running == false)
      return;
    //Some heavy logic
}
```

**Will this burn more CPU cycles compared to the approach of using an `std::condition_variable` as described** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544480/c-correct-way-to-pause-resume-an-stdthread/40544769?noredirect=1#comment68344743_40544769) **?**

Comment: Honestly, I dont understand `the_thread.join();` which is immediately after `thread_running=false`. I think setting `thread_running` to `false`, makes the thread's `while` loop to exit, followed by exiting of thread as well. What does `.join` serve in this case? Especially, when the thread uses *loop*.

Comment: @Nawaz The `join` call is needed because the OP didn't detach the thread. If he doesn't join the dead thread back to the main thread, the underlying thread resource(s) will be leaked (typically eventually crashing the app).

Comment: @Nawaz `the_thread.join()` is required from the main thread to wait for the worker thread to stop which is exit out of `GetData()` loop. If I dont do a `.join` then I face indeterminate application crashes. hence it is always good to have even if not entirely mandatory. But my question is different here as you see. I am not concerned about the `.join`

Comment: @MarkB: I didn't know that behavior of `.join`. I thought it *only* blocks the call, until the thread finishes. Even cppreference doesn't mention what you said about resource leak and crash!

Comment: @Nawaz let me walk back my statement a little bit: It works this way on the variety of Solaris/Linux systems I've worked with, but Windows may handle it more gracefully.

Comment: @Nawaz: _"Even cppreference doesn't mention what you said"_ [Sure it does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread)! This is basic, standard-mandated behaviour. Join your threads!

Comment: With the strategy of using an atomic, your thread *isn't paused at all*. It will burn a CPU core constantly checking if that boolean is true or false over and over and over and over at a speed of 4 GHz. You want the condition_variable, no questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A condition variable is useful when you want to conditionally halt another thread or not.  So you might have an always-running "worker" thread that waits when it notices it has nothing to do to be running.

The atomic solution requires your UI interaction synchronize with the worker thread, or very complex logic to do it asynchronously.

As a general rule, your UI response thread should never block on non-ready state from worker threads.

```
struct worker_thread {
  worker_thread( std::function<void()> t, bool play = true ):
    task(std::move(t)),
    execute(play)
  {
    thread = std::async( std::launch::async, [this]{
      work();
    });
  }
  // move is not safe.  If you need this movable,
  // use unique_ptr<worker_thread>.
  worker_thread(worker_thread&& )=delete;
  ~worker_thread() {
    if (!exit) finalize();
    wait();
  }
  void finalize() {
    auto l = lock();
    exit = true;
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  void pause() {
    auto l = lock();
    execute = false;
  }
  void play() {
    auto l = lock();
    execute = true;
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  void wait() {
    Assert(exit);
    if (thread)
      thread.get();
  }
private:
  void work() {
    while(true) {
      bool done = false;
      {
        auto l = lock();
        cv.wait( l, [&]{
          return exit || execute;
        });
        done = exit; // have lock here
      }
      if (done) break;
      task();
    }
  }
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() {
     return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
  }
  std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  bool exit = false;
  bool execute = true;
  std::function<void()> task;
  std::future<void> thread;
};
```

or somesuch.

This owns a thread.  The thread repeatedly runs task so long as it is in `play()` mode.  If you `pause()` the next time `task()` finishes, the worker thread stops.  If you `play()` before the `task()` call finishes, it doesn't notice the `pause()`.

The only wait is on destruction of `worker_thread`, where it automatically informs the worker thread it should exit and it waits for it to finish.

You can manually `.wait()` or `.finalize()` as well.  `.finalize()` is async, but if your app is shutting down you can call it early and give the worker thread more time to clean up while the main thread cleans things up elsewhere.

`.finalize()` cannot be reversed.

Code not tested.

Comment: Thanks for such a vivid answer. Hence, accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you already answered this in your original question: You'll be creating and destroying the worker thread each time it's needed. This may or may not be an issue in your actual application.

Comment: In my original question, completing stopping the thread & starting a new one is really an issue. I could even see the lag when I press the UI button many times to play/pause the worker thread. That is the root reason whey I am for alternatives to not stopping the thread. Also, I read that cleaning up a thread & starting a new one needs OS to allocate resources for the thread which is a heavy affair. Right ?

Comment: You saw the delayed because of joining all the spawned threads. A single thread spawn would not be noticeable

Comment: @user1095108 Agree wrt Desktop machines. My code is getting used on mobiles & low power hardware as well. And on a mid-range android phone, If I specifically tap on the pause play button many times causing this thread to start & stop, then a slight lag shows up once in a 15 times approx

Answer (score 1):

There's two different problems being solved and it may depend on what you're actually doing. One problem is "I want my thread to run until I tell it to stop." The other seems to be a case of "I have a producer/consumer pair and want to be able to notify the consumer when data is ready." The `thread_running` and `join` method works well for the first of those. The second you may want to use a mutex and condition because you're doing more than just using the state to trigger work. Suppose you have a `vector<Work>`. You guard that with the mutex, so the condition becomes `[&work] (){ return !work.empty(); }` or something similar. When the wait returns, you hold the mutex so you can take things out of work and do them. When you're done, you go back to wait, releasing the mutex so the producer can add things to the queue.

You may want to combine these techniques. Have a "done processing" atomic that all of your threads periodically check to know when to exit so that you can join them. Use the condition to cover the case of data delivery between threads.

Comment: My need is not as complex as the scenario you explained. My need is only to play or pause the thread. Thats it. Hence, I am thinking only an `std::atomic` variable `thread_running` would suffice to execute the heavy logic in `GetData()` or not execute the logic in `GetData()`

Comment: My problem is hand is not a producer consumer problem. It is just  self contained worker_thread which needs to be paused & resumed frequently. Do you think that I still need to use a `std::condition_variable` to achieve this ?

Comment: You need the wait() or the thread will needlessly burn cpu cycles

Comment: Neither of them is really the best choice for pause resume. The condition is probably less resource intensive in general. Lots of mutex implementations have some sort of waiting queue so that when you say "wait for this to be true then re-acquire the mutex" what you're really saying is "any time someone releases the mutex, acquire it, check my condition, and return true if the condition passes, otherwise release the mutex and try again". You do need to make sure that every time you change the flag, you do it while holding the mutex, but...

Comment: @user1095108 This is what I wanted to confirm. If I am burning CPU cycles then yes, I will use `std::condition_variable` & `wait()`.

Comment: @Charlie I must say that C++'s `std::atomic` is pretty solid. If I am using an atomic variable to check `thread_running` state, then I don't need to protect it using an `std::mutex`. I've tested this thing on osx, ios & android by wildly tapping on the play/pause button of my app UI. when using `std::atomic` you do not need `mutex` protection.     Apart from this as you say, `condition_variable` is less resource intensive. So, I will use the same for my code. thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @NelsonP It's not that atomic will be wrong, or even that it won't work. The check for work would be pretty fast every time through the loop, but having a thread that exits and needs to be respawned vs. a thread that waits for a notification is probably a bigger thing to consider. `while (true) { if (some_atomic_bool) { ...  do work ...}}` will basically burn a core on that thread when the condition is false. `while (true) { some_condition.wait(...); ... do work ...}}` in a well implemented system should put the thread to sleep and only wake it when the condition might have changed.

Comment: @Charlie Agree. Thanks for the explanation. I accepted your answer